# How do I store GeoJson in MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, odm

I'm trying to store a location in a GeoJson format in MongoDb using Doctrine ODM:
What I do is :

The mapping:

```
class Coordinates
{

    /** @MongoDB\String */
    protected $type;

    /** @MongoDB\Hash */
    protected $coordinates;

    public function __construct($type='Point',$coordinates)
    {
        $this->setType($type);
        $this->setCoordinates($coordinates);
    }
```

When I try to store one location I get it as follow :

```
coordinates: { type: "Point", coordinates: { 0: -6.855243444442749, 1: 33.9704221689807 } }
```

which is not the GeoJson format.
The correct format should be

```
   coordinates: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -6.855243444442749,33.9704221689807 ] }
```

How Can I achieve this ? 
Thank you very much !

Edit!
This is How I store it in PHP :

```
$coordinates=new Coordinates('Point',[$lng,$lat]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ! 
I got my answer on twitter :P 
I should have mapped the whole coordinates field as a Hash